# Unable to print the result after tokenizing string

Tags: c

I need help figuring out why the following code won't work. I want to split the buf string into tokens, and save it into the struct char *array field. And print out its contents.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct parser{
    char *array[10];
};

void stages(char buf[]){
    struct parser t;
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok (buf, "|");

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        t.array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok (NULL, "|");
    }

}

int main() {
    struct parser t;
    char buf[] ="ls < one | more | sort";
    int i = 0;

    stages(buf);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        printf("%s\n", t.array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `t` in the function `stages` is a local variable.

This is different than the variable `t` in main.

To print `t` in `main` you need to pass a pointer to `struct parser` to the function and remove the local variable `t`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct parser{
    char *array[10];
};

void stages(char buf[],struct parser *ptr){
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok (buf, "|");

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        ptr->array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok (NULL, "|");
    }

}

int main() {
    struct parser t;
    char buf[] ="ls < one | more | sort";
    int i = 0;

    stages(buf,&t);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        printf("%s\n", t.array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

memory allocated for struct parser t, in function named void stages(char buf[]);
will be in stack and as soon as the function returns that memory will be deleted 
by compiler. So  you can't print values of struct parser t in main.

If you want to print the value either you return that structure from the function 
or you can pass the pointer from main to that function.